# Convert to SARGable query

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I want to write a query to search the containing string in the table.

Table:

```
Create table tbl_sarg
(
    colname varchar(100),
    coladdres varchar(500)
);
```

Note: I just want to use `Index Seek` for searching on 300 millions of records.

Index:

```
create nonclustered index ncidx_colname on tbl_sarg(colname);
```

Sample Records:

```
insert into tbl_sarg values('John A Mak','HNo 102 Street Road Uk');
insert into tbl_sarg values('Shawn A Meben','Church road USA');
insert into tbl_sarg values('Lee Decose','ShopNo 22 K Mark UK');
insert into tbl_sarg values('James Don','A Mall, 90 feet road UAE');
```

Query 1:

```
select * from tbl_sarg
where colname like '%ee%'
```

Actual Execution Plan:

[image]

Query 2:

```
select * from tbl_sarg
where charindex('ee',colname)>0
```

Actual Execution Plan:

[image]

Query 3:

```
select * from tbl_sarg
where patindex('%ee%',colname)>0
```

Actual Execution Plan:

[image]

How to force the query processor to use the index seek instead table/index scan on large data set?

Comment: None of those queries are SARGable, as a leading wild card means a "normal" index is useless. Indexes on `(n)(var)char` datatypes sort the letters in collation order left to right. If you're looking for a value that contains the string `'ee'` anywhere in the value, no sorting is going to help you there. If you need to perform queries like this you'll need to consider a full text index.

Comment: Any other option rather than full text index?

Comment: If it's only ever going to be `'%ee%'` you're searching for, then create a persisted computed column. Otherwise your only other option is to suffer a table scan every time you want to do a leading wild card search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search argument, or SARG in short, is a filter predicate that enables the optimizer to rely on
index order. The filter predicate uses the following form (or a variant with two delimiters of a
range, or with the operand positions flipped):
WHERE `<column> <operator> <expression>`

Such a filter is **sargable** if:

1. You don’t apply manipulation to the filtered column.
2. The operator identifies a consecutive range of qualifying rows in the index. That’s the
   case with operators like =, >, >=, <, <=, BETWEEN, LIKE with a known prefix, and so on.
   That’s not the case with operators like <>, LIKE with a wildcard as a prefix.

In most cases, when you apply manipulation to the filtered column, the optimizer doesn’t
try to be too smart and understand the meaning of the calculation, and if index ordering
can still be relied on. It simply assumes that the result values might sort differently than the
source values, and therefore index ordering can’t be trusted.

So why doesn’t SQL Server use the index for the `%ee%` query?  Pretend for a moment that you held a phone book in your hand, and I asked you to find everyone whose last name contains the letters %ee%.  You would have to scan every single page in the phone book, because the results would include things like:

- Anne Lee
- Lee Yung
- Kathlee
- Aleen

  When I asked you for all last names containing `%ee%` anywhere in the name, my query was not sargable – meaning, you couldn’t leverage the indexes to do an index seek.

That’s where **[SQL Server’s Full Text Search](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/)** comes in.

Comment: Elements of this comment appear to be lifted directly from a Brent Ozar article. Full article is here https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/

Answer (score 2):

All the queries that you have posted, by definition are not SARgable, for instance, the use of '%..%'' automatically force the Query Engine to do a Scan, the other case is the use of functions (as charindex or patindex) inside your column inside a predicate.

Here some post: https://bertwagner.com/2017/08/22/how-to-search-and-destroy-non-sargable-queries-on-your-server/

Kimberly Tripp has written very interesting articles about it if for you is mandatory to execute this kind of query with wildcards, maybe it is worth to check about the possibility of using FullTextSearch feature.  My point is, or your limit and do a precise predicate into your queries or you will have to change of strategy, almost forget, don't try to force the use of Seek with HINT, I can't see that this medicine will be better than the illness.